# C# RawPrinter helper class doesnt work for normal printer

Tags: c#, class, printing

I took the c# helper class from [this link (Microsoft site)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091). Firstly it work with the thermal/dot-matrix printer. But I use this class for the second project which is normal canon printer. But cannot work. From Windows print queue it shows only for a brief moment. And suddenly cleared but the printer doesn't print anything. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: The data you sent via RawPrinter vary according to the printer's internal language. Have you modify your data for the canon printer? Or why not just use the PrintDocument?

Comment: Martheen is right. You're going to have to tailor your print data to every model of printer you intend to support. I don't think sending raw data is the approach you want to use if you intend to support more than a very small number of printers.

Comment: @CareyGregory My project before (that i use for dot-matrix printer) can also send to canon printer (same canon printer). But I dont know why it doesnt work this time.. any idea which line of code i should modify? Thanks a lot..

Comment: You'll find that some printers might work with the same raw data, but many others won't. I have no idea which line of code you should modify but I do know you'll have to figure this out for hundreds of models of printers if you use this approach. Trying to use raw data for printing is going to be a _huge_ effort that's almost certainly not worth it.

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks for your opinion. I will look for other way such as PrintDocument class. Maybe it is a bit longer as we need to register the printing event unlike the raw printer helper class with is only few lines of calling the code.

Comment: The `PrintDocument` class is absolutely a better way to go than raw printing. Using raw printing is like having to develop a print driver for every model of printer you intend to support.